# Is there a nice way to get length of slice elem in map regardless of its concrete type?

Tags: go, design-patterns

For example, I have two maps, namely `map[string][]structA`and `map[string][]int`.

I want to iterate the map and print out length of every slice, can I implement this in a single function?

I tried to define an interface and implement it in two kinds of slices, but the compiler just cannot do the type cast.

```
type Container interface{
    Len() int
}

type Slice1 []int
func (s Slice1) Len() int {
    return len(s)
}

type Slice2 []StructA
func (s Slice2) Len() int {
    return len(s)
}

func iterate(input map[string]Container) {
    for key, value := range input {
        log.Printf("key:%s, lenght:%d", key, value.Len())
    }
}

func main() {
    // cannot do the type cast
    iterate(map[string]Slice1{})
    iterate(map[string]Slice2{})
}
```

Comment: *"can I implement this in a singler function?"* -- No, not with those types and without resorting to reflection. You have to either change the types to one and the same, or use reflection, or wait for Go2 generics (i believe 2022 sometime in late summer they are expected to land)

Comment: As for why you cannot do the conversion (note Go has no type *casts*) you can read about that here: https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"can I implement this in a single function?"*

Yes, but the way you called the function should be changed. Convert your maps to `map[string]Container` and then call the `iterate`

```
func main() {
    // cannot do the type cast
    map1 := map[string][]int{
        `key`: []int{1,2,3},
    }

    map1Container := make(map[string]Container)
    for key, value := range map1 {
        map1Container[key] = Slice1(value)
    }

    map2 := map[string][]StructA{
        `key1`: []StructA{{}, {}},
    }
    map2Container := make(map[string]Container)
    for key, value := range map2 {
        map2Container[key] = Slice2(value)
    }

    iterate(map1Container)
    iterate(map2Container)
}
```

Output:

```
2021/07/06 12:15:25 key:key, lenght:3
2021/07/06 12:15:25 key:key1, lenght:2
```

`iterate` function expected `map[string]Container` type parameter. So you can initiate that with `Container` type and inside the map with different keys, you can include different `Container`'s implementations.

```
func main() {
    // cannot do the type cast
    iterate(map[string]Container{
        `ke1`: Slice1([]int{
            1, 2, 3,
        }),
        `ke2`: Slice2([]StructA{
            {},
            {},
        }),
    })
}
```

Output:

```
2021/07/06 11:57:55 key:ke1, lenght:3
2021/07/06 11:57:55 key:ke2, lenght:2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the map could be really big so that performance do matters, I might give up the idea using a single function as  result.